# Deny Direct Access to Lists in SharePoint-Hosted Add-in

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

Not finding any real answer to this question, so not sure if I am articulating my question correctly...

**SCENARIO:**
I am creating an college registration form for students using a SharePoint-hosted Add-in. Requirements make it thus and MUST be all self contained rather than split up (cross-domain). Therefore, lists and libraries are created by the add-in when deployed. Students are able to register and add documents just fine.

The problem I am seeing is that if a student happens to know the direct URL to the list or library, instead of using the GUI design, he/she would then be able to view/edit all the other student records and personal information.

Aside from naming the lists crazy names, is there anything I can do? Worried that some one might read through a JavaScript file, and figure out locations. I want to force the user to ONLY use the GUI (ASPX page) and not see the SharePoint side of things.

**CAVEAT:** 
There might be certain people who will need to access these lists directly to "Open with Explorer".

Comment: For the custom list can't you set 'Read items that were created by the user' in the advance setting for custom list?

Comment: Once you run the installed app and go to the list directly, there are no Advanced Settings options that I can recall.

Comment: Also, the issue would still be allowing others to see everything.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.ramontorras.net/2015/05/07/how-to-restrict-editing-in-sp-list-only-to-own-items/ and http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97011/list-and-list-item-permission-and-security-in-sharepoint-hosted-app.   It seems that you can set the 'Security Bits' to 2.  Allowing others to see everything shouldn't be a problem as you can always assign owner/higher permissions to enable them to see everything in the list.

Comment: So it sounds like I can, depending on a user' role, set the security bits on the fly when they visit that page? If multiple people are accessing at once, does this affect the others or does it work in their own little instance?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean here 'does this affect the others or does it work in their own little instance'? but you can certainly give elevated permissions to certain individuals. while others have security bit set to 2

Comment: If you can change to provider hosted model then you can use App only permissions. That way with App permissions you can create the item but user won't have direct permissions on those lists.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. All each help solve my issues. I assumed that what I wanted to do given my restrictions was not possible. Looking in to security bits. Thanks!

Comment: My instructions are that I can use a provider-hosted app BUT must only use what a SharePoint-hosted app can do and nothing else. I know, lame. So, why do my requirements even say I can created a Provider-hosted add-in? Very frustrating :-( Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found is though security bits and to remove the allitems view from the list.